# JToggleButton HideActionText hides Button-Text

Tags: swing, jbutton

I have created a `JToggleButton` with the Netbeans editor, `setHideActionText` to `True` and added an Action. However, the Button displays without text at all, all I see is a small square (like a checkbox). The Text of the Button is set to "b" and the Action used is `StyledEditorKit.BoldAction` and I haven't set any Icon.

If I don't add the Action it's working fine. Is this a bug or am I missing something (probably very stupid)?

Maybe more clearly:

I want the button to show the text that I set with `setText`, not the one I set with `Action.putValue(Action.NAME, "Some Name")` and I don't want to display an Icon.

Comment: what exactly do you want to reach, and why do you think the hideActionText gives you that?

Comment: Is this clearer now? I think that the JavaDoc suggests that the method does what I want. "...which determines whether the button displays text from the Action"

Comment: out of curiousity only: why do you change the name of the boldAction?

Comment: I want to have it displayed as a `ToggleButton` with the text `b` on it, but I want to display it in a menu, too, but there it should be called `Bold`

Comment: ahh, thanks, about what I expected - just wanted to be sure :-) You might consider to use wrapping actions around the bare-bones: this way they are independently configurable (in their visual properties), but share the same basic action behaviour (like selected, enabled)

Comment: I guess usually I would have done that, but it's part of an academic task, and we're supposed to use as few Actions as possible. My Professor is working with swing for a long time now. I'm not sure, either swing is quite buggy (or better: has a lot of unexpected behavior) in general, or the tasks are deliberately designed to let us run into the rough edges of swing (as I know my Prof, it's probably the latter ;D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour, as documented in the api of setHideTextAction (why-o-why don't you read the javadoc, it's there for a reason):

```
 * Sets the <code>hideActionText</code> property, which determines
 * whether the button displays text from the <code>Action</code>.
 * This is useful only if an <code>Action</code> has been
 * installed on the button.
 *
```

don't touch the property and be happy ;-)

Edit: seeing more clearly now - thanks for the clarification

- if true, the button's text property is *not* touched when the action's name property is changed
- undocumented: setting it to true, nulls the button's text property

To have a "sticky" (button defined only) text property, sequence of method calls matters (which shouldn't be case .. but then ..) First that hideText

```
button.setHideActionText(true);
button.setText("myText");
```

Comment: It's hiding the *button-text* as well as the Action-Text. If I set `hideActionText` to False it shows the text from the Action, like I'd expect. If I set it to True, it shows neither, not the text from the Action, nor the one from the Button.

Comment: exactly what the doc is stating :-) If false, all properties of the Action are synched to the corresponding properties of the button, if true, the button's text property is set to null.

Comment: Well how I understand it: If false: Use text from Action, if Action has been set, or fallback to the text from the button. If true: Don't use the text from the action, but always the ones from the Button

Comment: Ah, thanks, that was it, `setText` *after* `setHideActionText` (PS: you wrote `setHideText`, I can't edit that) Too bad it's not documented.

Comment: Filed a bug report, requesting documentation enhancement.

Comment: Wow, the fact that sequence of calls matters is really annoying. I wish they'd make the original button's text visible if you call setHideActionText(true) at any time instead of setting it to null. That'd horrible. I have to refactor my code because of this, to set the names for the actions instead of the buttons. Lame!